# Android - Set TextView background programatically to drawable before API 24

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to set the background of an TextView that acts as a button to an XML vector.

```
    if (condition) {
       textViewButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selected);
      } else if (condition) {
       textViewButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_correct);
      } else {
        textViewButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_unselected);
      }
```

I thing this was introduced in API24 and I can't load it in my API22 test phone as I get the following error:

> 

```
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070069
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1324)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:828)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16251)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatTextView.java:113)<
```

Is there any way to acomplish this changes to imageView design programaticaly for older API's?(works just fine on API 29 and 30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the recommended way

`textViewButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.button_selected));`

If it doesn't work in your app's `build.gradle` you need to include:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

And add the following to `onCreate`:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked in the end, at first I still got the same error but then I noticed that Android Studio has placed my "button_unselected" drawable in v24 folder and the other button drawables in xxhdpi folder, after moving the file it worked in the end.